# Looking for Pseudo-code for Fortune's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'd really appreciate if someone who ever dealt with Fortune's algorithm for generating Delaunay-triangulations presented me a rather low-level pseudo-code of the algorithm! I read the one on wikipedia but it's a bit confusing and looks high-level, and any piece of code I could find had the original C implementation's inconveniences.

I'd like to implement it in C++, but in a way that the output generated is in the form of (my own) classes I'm going to use (vertices, edges and triangles as objects). So I need to understand everything and implement it from scratch.

I also read the description of the algorithm, and I know what it does and how, but this is still to abstract for me right now. However, I'd also be happy with a similar description going into the (implementation) details, it doesn't have to be code-like!

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using CGAL ? Delaunay triangulation is very very tricky to get right: the roundoff errors you are bound to encounter will ruin any implementation which doesn't use adaptive precision arithmetic.

Comment: The only reason is that I've somehow never heard about it before :) This really looks very promising, apart from the commercial licence for commercial uses, but I guess it's OK. I will play around with it a little to see if it fits my needs enough, but if no one comes up with a nice pseudocode and it's really that hard to implement, you might want to repeat this as an answer that I can mark as best!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it took me about a month to fully understand Fortune's algorithm, I wrote my seminar school work about it. When you get it, it seems very easy :)

Here is my [description of Fortune's algorithm](http://blog.ivank.net/fortunes-algorithm-and-implementation.html), with imperative pseudocode and implementation details.

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks exactly like what I'm looking for! I'll take a closer look soon, but I do believe this is it, so I'll mark it as an answer :)

Comment: @Ivan I know this is crypto-commenting, but this is driving me mad... I read the original algorithm from Steven Fortune in his paper from '87, and it is *not* what is described and implemented almost everywhere, including your page. Fortune's paper does not have a beach line made of parabolas but conceptually deals with a list of arcs of hyperbola (even though it's not necessary to store it explicitly). I suspect that the "usual" explanation was found by somebody else later (e.g. one or more of de Berg, Cheong, van Kreveld and Overmars) as an equivalent. But I'd like to hear your opinion!