# Voronoi Diagram: How to implement parabloas?

Tags: algorithm, math

I've been trying to implement a Voronoi Diagram using Fortunes Algorithm. I understand how it works but I'm stuck at how to store the parabolic arcs.

I understand all this is needed for the parabola is the sweeplines' `Y` position and the sites position but I'm I don't understand what to do with it.

I found this equation online (via this [site](http://www.cescg.org/CESCG99/RCuk/)):

[image: equation]

What is `X` in this equation?

Comment: This seems more suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/ i guess

Comment: I'd say it's applicable here since this is for a computer algorithm,

Comment: @sasha I understand the maths behind it, but I'm struggling to translate into code.

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738038/pseudo-code-for-fortunes-algorithm) of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that *y = ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c* is the equation of a parabola with vertical axis. In this case, *a,b,c* are given in more detail. *l<sub>y</sub>* is a parameter which describes the current position of the sweep line and therefore influences the shape of the parabola. So your equation describes a whole family of parabolas, with *p<sub>j,x</sub>* and *p<sub>j,y</sub>* being the coordinates of the point you actually store in your data structure.

Comment: Could you give an example please?